# How to use the same drop folder for consecutive builds with tfs 2012?

Tags: build, tfs

What I'm trying to do is have a single drop-off location for a given solution no matter the build number. The problem arises from TFS wanting to append the build number to the directory structure after the specified drop location, as in

```
...drop-location\BuildDefitionName\BuildNumber
```

So my first solution (probably not that great of an idea) was to make the build number defined in the build definition static. This worked, but only for the first build. After that, tfs won't allow me to build another build within the same definition with the same number.

So what are my options on getting to a single drop location? The goal is to always have the latest working (unit tests passed) version at a pre-determined location. I also only want to keep the latest version, so no need for retention. Is the only option to go and edit the build process template? I'm a bit wary about this, because doesn't that mean I'd have to repeat the procedure for every solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the build workflow if you want than.
In the build workflow, check the sequence called "Update drop location".
In that sequence the build number is created for you. If you want to bypass that build number, you need to modify the assign section before "Set Drop Location".
By default that assign is

`BuildDropProvider.CombinePaths(BuildDetail.DropLocationRoot, BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.Name, BuildDetail.BuildNumber)`

you can put
`BuildDropProvider.CombinePaths(BuildDetail.DropLocationRoot, BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.Name, String.Empty)`

You can reuse the modified build workflow accross multiple solutions.

I hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

i have updated the Build template xaml file and it seem to work fine